# jquery inline validation for numbers and numbers with characters?

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-plugins

I have a form in that some different types of input fields like for `url, letters, letters with numbers, and only for numbers`. To make them inline validation I picked this [jquery inline validator plugin](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine). It is working fine for url and letters validation but I am not getting how to make validate numbers only like `(23224567445)` and both letters and numbers in mix like`(A3F00)`? I have searched the documentation but I am not getting it properly.
For url vaidation I have done like this

```
Url validation
<input type="text" class="validate[required,custom[url]]" name="link_url" id="link_url"/>

letters validation
<input type="text" name="firstname" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetterSp],maxSize[100],ajax[ajaxNameCallPhp]] text-input" id="firstname"/>
```

So can someone kindly tell me how to validate only numbers and numbers with alphabets as example above I have given. Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this "custom[onlyLetterNumber]"

```
    <input value="too many spaces obviously" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetterNumber]]" type="text" name="special" id="special" />
```